# How to pass params to the method if a user leaves few params empty and wants to omit?

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have one web service to which i need to send multiple params but it's upto user that he can leave few empty and few filled but the problem is that if we pass empty or null the web service returns nothing and the vendor is not modifying it.

so we need to do something on our end.

I have done this that i took one string varaible and then append this to the url.

```
   If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEqptType.Text) Then
                Dim command As String = "Equips?$filter= TypeID eq 'Safety'"
            ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEquipID.Text) Then
                Dim command As String = "Equips?$filter= EquipID eq 'FIRE EXT 150'"
            ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPlant.Text) Then
                Dim command As String = "Equips?$filter= Plant eq 'MfgSys'"
            ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDescription.Text) Then
                Dim command As String = "Equips?$filter= Description eq 'Fire Extinguisher 150_1'"
            End If
```

but what I need to achieve is that if one param is empty i.e. not filled, then it shouldn't be passed to the webservice in the query string. Is there any short and solid way? bcz If I do, i will have to write a lot of if else condtions.

Comment: Are the filters mutually exclusive? I mean your code allows only for one filter condition.

Comment: Could you show us an example with two filters, please?

Comment: @AndrewMorton sure: Equips?$filter=Plant eq 'MfgSys' and EquipID eq 'FIRE EXT 150'

Comment: @Steve no multiple, but if one of them is empty then it shall not be passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have clarified your problem I think you could resolve the problem in this way.

First build a class that generically handles the empty string condition.
We could call it ConditionBuilder

```
Public Class ConditionBuilder
    
    ' We store the valid condition here
    Dim conditions As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)


    ' We add the condition to the list only if the checkstring is not empty
    Public Sub AddCondition(checkString As String, condition As String)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(checkString) Then
            conditions.Add(condition)
        End If
    End Sub

    ' We build the result query string from the conditions that we have stored
    Public Function GetCondition() As String
        If conditions.Count = 0 Then
            Return ""
        End If
        
        Return "Equips?$filter = " & String.Join(" and ", conditions)
    End Function
        
End Class
```

Now we don't need to clutter our code with many checks, but we call directly the conditionbuilder in this way

```
Sub Main
    Dim cb As ConditionBuilder = New ConditionBuilder()
    cb.AddCondition(txtEqptType.Text, "TypeID eq 'Safety'")
    cb.AddCondition(txtEquipID.Text,"EquipID eq 'FIRE EXT 150'")
    cb.AddCondition(txtPlant.Text,"$Plant eq 'MfgSys'")
    cb.AddCondition(txtDescription.Text, "$Description eq 'Fire Extinguisher 150_1'")
    Dim condition = cb.GetCondition()
    Console.WriteLine(condition)
End Sub
```

Notice how I have inverted the logic in the String.IsNullOrEmpty. If I have understood it correctly you want to pass a parameter only if the associated textbox is not empty. Consider also that perhaps you should change the String.IsNullOrEmpty with String.IsNullOrWitheSpace.

Actually this code writes fixed text for each of your textboxes. But if you need to replace the text between the single quotes with the actual content of the text box you can change this line

```
    conditions.Add(condition)
```

with

```
    condition.Add(string.Format(condition, checkString))
```

Of course this means that you need to change also the point where you call AddCondition to insert the format required by String.Format to execute the string substitution.

So you should have

```
 cb.AddCondition(txtEqptType.Text, "TypeID eq '{0}'")
```

and so on for the other calls to AddCondition

Comment: let me try this seems promising

Answer (score 0):

Put all your values into a `List(Of String)`, join those with the appropriate operator using `String.Join` and then concatenate whatever else you need, e.g.

```vb
Dim days As New List(Of String)

days.Add("Monday")
days.Add("Wednesday")
days.Add("Friday")

Console.WriteLine("I work on {0}.", String.Join(" and ", days))
```

That would output:

> I work on Monday and Wednesday and Friday.

You could add and combination of days there and it would work as expected. You can use the same principle to join any list of substrings with a common separating substring.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is the _lot of_ if - else if - else if - else conditions

Comment: @Steve, then you'd be wrong. You still have to test each `TextBox` individually to see whether it has been populated or not and construct the appropriate criterion with the value if there is one. There's no magic way around that. In fact, they should all be separate `If` statements. The issue is how to combine those criteria into a single command statement regardless of the combination and I have demonstrated that.